# Upgrading sendmail - what's involved?

Tags: sendmail

I need to upgrade a server from Sendmail 8.14.1 to 8.14.5. Im trying to compile a 'milter' and am having some issues with missing libraries.

Anything I should look out for? Can I just do the 'make install' and be happy? (Its already built)

Comment: Do you compile sendmail "by hand" or installing it via binary packages available for your operating system?

Comment: Compiled 'by hand'. Im a tad nervous about breaking the existing system by 'upgrading' it.

Comment: After you compile and install sendmail, compile and install libmilter. It would also help if you could tell us more about the milter in question and the libraries that you are having issues with.

Comment: No issues yet. Im writing a milter that will make a copy of all in and outbound mail and archive it.

Comment: You can use [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org) for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compile sendmail then you need to compile and install libmilter separately. After compiling and installing sendmail, you need to change to the libmilter directory and run `Build` and `Build install` there too.

Comment: I'll give MIMEDefang a spin and see what happens. TY.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking a patch version (third digit) bump in sendmail is a non-event.
Review the changelog, but you should just be able to do a `make install` with no problems.

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem with the milter you're trying to build -- You should confirm that before pulling the trigger (and ensure that you're building sendmail with the same options as the version already installed, for consistency and compatibility), but the patches shouldn't cause any new problems either way.

Comment: Are there any other options besides whats in devtools/Site/site.config.m4?

Comment: Have you read [the tips for building/installing sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org/tips/index)? There's a fairly extensive list, most of which is usually just left at defaults...